# A fuse slot has disappeared

Tags: electrical, fuse, fuse-panel

My 2003 Opel Agila has recently had a catastrophic electrical problem, and my electric mirrors do not work anymore. The recovery guy pulled out and replaced a few fuses, and I drove home all fine.

However, now my electric mirrors do not work, and now there is a missing fuse slot. There is no connecter in there at all, and there should be a fuse there. I have checked on the wiring diagrams of my service information and in my manual, and there should be a 15A fuse in this slot, circled in the picture:

[image]

This fuse also powers the radio, as well as the standard electric mirrors. **The radio will not work without this fuse**.

However now there is nothing in this slot in my car. I don't know what to do as I can't change the fuse box or anything as it is hardwired to the car.

I just put the fuse in and it falls out again as there it is just an empty hole. There is nothing at all there.
**How can I find my missing fusebox connector?**

Comment: Can you post a picture of your actual fuse box?

Comment: any wires hanging out that you can see? any melting in the fuse slot?

Comment: The slot is completely empty, there is nothing hanging out of the fuse box

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So beneath that fuse is a wiring terminal. It's obvious that your terminal got pushed in so far that the fuse spades no longer touch anything.

The good news is that everything is in there.  The bad news is you will have to dissemble everything and reseat the wiring terminals on the inner surface of that fuse box cover. That could be very ugly depending on where the fuse box is mounted. I'm guessing that assembly is all snapped together. Once you understand how engineers design snap together plastic parts you can begin a dissemble process. If you go in heavy handed you are just going to break stuff.

This repair will require a whole lot of patience.  Or just a replacement fuse box?

Note. I'd be curious to see what the dealer quotes for this repair. Not sure about anyone else but I despise working underneath the instrument panel.

Comment: So I removed the driver storage tray, so I could see the fuse box better. Then I found the missing fuse slot, and all the connectors and wiring was just pushed out of it's hole, so it was above the fuse box as you look up at it. I got a G-Clamp as it was one on the outside and forced it back in with a fuse on the other side. This worked, and I can remove the fuse again (yes I did check!). I wouldn't recommend this normally though, as you could snap the fuses and get it stuck in the hole so you can't take it out again it it blows.